# Error while trying to plot C file in with gnuplot

Tags: c, plot

I was trying to learn plotting with gnu-plot trough a example with C programming but the following message keeps repeating when i try to plot:

```
"Warning: Skipping data file with no valid points"
"x rang is invalid"
```

I don't know what it meant with that. I compiled the file and it didn't give me any errors and this is from a already made example. Why exactly am i not able to plot?

The code is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double t = 0.0, x, y;
    FILE  *fp;
    fp = fopen("data6-7.txt","w");
    do
    {
        x = cos(2*M_PI*t);
        y = sin(2*M_PI*t);

        fprintf(fp, "%f %f %f\n", t, x, y);

        t = t + 0.01;
    } while (t <= 1.0);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What c file did you try to plot, and why are there invalid characters in your code? And where are you calling `gnuplot`?

Comment: @iharob: that's the backslash character when using a shift-jis encoding

Comment: @iharob I don't know, i was using a example a teacher gave me, but it's not working.

Comment: Please post the example your teacher gave, and plotting with gnuplot from c is generally not necessary, since you can run the program and generate the data file and then invoke `gnuplot` from a bash script anyway.

Comment: Well....that's pretty much the whole example right there.after that it asks to type gnuplot in the terminal and plot the following:

gnuplot> plot gdata6-7.txth using 1:2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you compile and run your program, you must create a `plot` file telling `gnuplot` how to read your data (much easier than cramming all option on the command line). Example for your case:

```
plot \
"data6-7.txt" using 1:2 title 'cos', \
"data6-7.txt" using 1:3 title 'sin'
```

Save it as `myplot.plt`. Then call `gnuplot` with:

```
gnuplot -p myplot.plt
```

The format of the `.plt` file should be fairly obvious. You can plot data from any file against data from any other file. In the case of only one data file (like here), the format is:

```
plot \
"filename" using (colum #):(column #) title 'sometitle', \
......
```

The plot command is **one line** (so line continuations are required). The `(colum #):(column #)` just says plot data from the first column # as the independent data against the next column # ad the dependent values.

There are many, many options/tweaks for plotting (plot to `.png`, axis labels, scaling, etc..). Take a look at the manual (and examples) online or usually in your `/usr/share/gnuplot/4.X/gnuplot.pdf` file.